# My Super Simple PHP Plugin is Appending an Extra Whitespace to its Output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, plugins

I am brand spanking new to PHP so as a challenge I decided to try to design a super simple PHP plugin that would output a text greeting based on the time of day  for a user. In order to use my plugin, you simply drop the .php file in your 'includes' folder then insert the line  where you want the greeting to appear on your page.

My problem is that my plugin (named 'timely-greeting.php') is adding an extra whitespace at the end of the text output. I think I have narrowed down the problem, but first for clarity's sake, here is my whole PHP plugin code (also, I'm a noob so I'm sure I've made plenty of other logical errors/mistakes here so please let me know):

```
<?php
//timely-greeting.php

// Handle AJAX request (start)
if( isset($_POST['name']) ){

    // Storing the timezone offset from the jQuery code
    $timezone_offset_minutes = $_POST['name'];

    // Convert minutes to seconds
    $timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset_minutes*60, false);
    //JS code is needed to retrieve the user's timezone dynamically so we have it set statically for now
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone_name);

    // Morning start and end times (12:00 AM - 11:59 AM)
    $morningStart = '0000';
    $morningEnd   = '1159';
    // Afternoon start and end times (12:00 PM - 4:59 PM)
    $afterNoonStart = '1200';
    $afterNoonEnd   = '1659';
    // Evening start and end times (5:00 PM - 11:59 PM)
    $eveningStart = '1700';
    $eveningEnd   = '2359';

    // YOU CAN EDIT THE GREETINGS HERE
    $greetings = array(
        "morning"   => "Good morning",
        "afternoon" => "Good afternoon",
        "evening"   => "Good evening"
        );

    // Retrieving the current time
    $now = date('H:i');
    $now = str_replace(":" , "" , "$now");

     //Checking the current time of day in order to display the correct greeting
    if ( ($now >= $morningStart) && ( $now <= $morningEnd ) ) {
        echo $greetings["morning"];

    } elseif ( ($now >= $afterNoonStart) && ( $now <= $afterNoonEnd) ) {
        echo $greetings["afternoon"];

    } elseif ( ($now >= $eveningStart) && ( $now <= $eveningEnd) ) {
        echo $greetings["evening"];
    }

exit;// Handle AJAX request (end)
}
?>
<span id="message"></span>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Timezone offset Retrieval jQuery -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var timezone_offset_minutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  timezone_offset_minutes = timezone_offset_minutes == 0 ? 0 : -timezone_offset_minutes;

  console.log( "TZ offset in minutes: " + timezone_offset_minutes); // logging the timezone offset in min

  $.ajax({
 /******* IMPORTANT: EDIT 'url' BELOW *******/
        url: '../includes/timely-greeting.php', //replace the 'url:' with the new filepath for this file
        type: 'post',
        data: {name: timezone_offset_minutes},
        success: function(response){
        $('#message').text(response);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And this is how and where my plug-in gets used in my header.php file:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="settings.php"><?php include('includes/timely-greeting.php');?>, <?php echo $_SESSION['loggedInUser']; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
```

This is the output I am looking for:

> Good evening, Nick

But I am actually getting an extra space after the greeting, creating a space between the greeting and the comma which looks like this:

> Good evening , Nick

So far I've narrowed down my problem to this line:

```
<span id="message"></span>
```

Notice that  extra space between 'evening' and the comma seems to go away when I use a `<div>` instead of a `<span>` but the `<div>` of course creates a line break which also is a problem. This is the output now:

> Good evening
>
> , Nick

And of course my next idea was to keep the `<div>` tags and just add a style to make the tag inline, like `style="display: inline;` but that just brings me back to square one. This is my output when I use `<div>` tags and style them to be inline.

> Good evening , Nick

SIDE NOTE: I've tried looking for a BOM to see if that's what is causing the extra space. I'm using Brackets as my code editor. I tried looking for extra characters using the Nano editor but couldn't find anything.

I would love to get the bottom of this and maybe also see if there is a better way to write this code (I'm sure there is). That way, I might be able to avoid running into these problems in the first place.

Comment: your including you script in a weird place, including the js code as well ... this cant possibly be valid html

Comment: Ok so please can you tell me where should I include the script? This is a plugin, meaning all the code needs to be self-contained. Also, calling your JS scripts at the bottom of your code is the best practice, so I don't get what you mean by it not being valid HTML.

Comment: your inside an `<a>` tag,you cant just include everything. html has rules

Comment: any one can post a tutorial, does not mean its good, or even valid code

Comment: Ok, but does by chance having anything to do with the extra space being generated? So, back story: I created this plugin by following a tutorial where the instructor used a similar plugin in the exact same way, by using `<?php include('filename.php'); ?>` where he wanted the output to appear. Here is the link to that plugin: [link](https://github.com/coryetzkorn/php-store-hours). My instructor, _instructed_ us to use the include() function to include the plugin file wherever we wanted the output to appear.

Comment: Can you explain how a PHP plugin is used? How else can I use this plugin if I shouldn't be injecting its output using an include(). Also, I'm in an <a> tag. <a> tags are inline, what's the problem there?

Comment: I'm trying to think critically about this. Should I instead write a function inside my plugin that exposes the different greetings (stored in vars) that I can then echo in my header.php? Am I answering my own question? LOL

Comment: Delete the carriage return before the `<span>` tag.

Comment: Thank you Roamer-1888 but my apologies, I'm not sure what you mean. I don't see anything before my <span> tag. Do you mean the exit; call in my php?

Comment: I may have misread the code in the question.  Does the php genuinely abutt the html, or are there two separate files?

Comment: So I removed the exit; line of code and now my code is spitting out my answer plus the rest of the code that's in my plugin. And at the end of all that code, there STILL is a space at the end of the output lol

Comment: Roamer: I designed my plugin to be self-contained in just one file. I want to display its output in a specific spot in a header.php file I created in a separate project. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: So where are the doctype , html, head and body tags?

Comment: rtfm helped me think about how my approach could be incorrect because I am simply including the entire plugin in my header.php with this line of code: `<?php include('timely-greeting.php'); ?>` when I probably should have created a function in my plugin that exposes the variables instead. Then I can include() my php file at the top of my header.php and then in the spot I want the greeting to display I would do something like this `<?php echo $greeting; ?>

Comment: Ok so it's not a page, it's a plugin that only outputs one line of text that you use inside a different web page

Comment: Not too sure but I suspect it's something like that.

Comment: Go for a clear distinction between what is initially served and what is subsequently fetched via ajax.

Comment: As it turns out, the PHP plugin my instructor used in his tutorial has completely changed in the 3 years since the tutorial was released. I can't even recognize it. So I'm just going to assume it's NOT the right way to go about things and do a re-write. I'm also going to go complain to my instructor lol

Comment: ah see? that is my problem, I don't entirely understand how my ajax request works, but I'm just sending the timezone_offset_minutes in my request. Then PHP grabs it, turns it into the right timezone, and then that timezone is used to determine the right greeting to echo. But i suspect it has something to do with my 'success:' function()?

Comment: Yea so I'm not sure what the response var does in my ajax request. This line `success: function(response){
        $('#message').text(response);` seems to somehow be displaying the plugin's own code in its output..

Comment: The ajax looks OK. It displays whatever text is returned from the server in `<span id="message"></span>`.

Comment: Where does the ", Nick" part of the text come from?

Comment: Oh but when I removed the `exit;` line I started getting all of the actual code in my output. The comma Nick part is a global $_SESSION variable and get's added to the line in my header.php page where I'm trying to inject my plugin. this is the whole line in header.php `<li><a href="settings.php"><?php echo $greeting; ?>, <?php echo $_SESSION['loggedInUser']; ?></a></li>`

Comment: Sorry in the code above I mistakenly changed the code while I was experimenting around. This line `<?php echo $greeting; ?>` is actually currently this: `<?php include('includes/timely-greeting.php');?>` sorry

Comment: The overall architecture is a bit weird. I can't get my mind around it.

Comment: What I can't grasp is whether ", Nick" is in the initially served page or whether it is delivered in the AJAX response?

Comment: no no sorry ", Nick" has nothing to do with the plugin. It's just part of the rest of the message I'm trying to dynamically display.

Comment: Then, in all probability, your extra whitespace has nothing to do with the plugin either. You probably serve " , Nick" in the initial page.

Comment: hm maybe I can split the plugin up into two files to make the architecture more organized.

Comment: No the whitespace isn't coming from my other code, I am sure of that. I can see the whitespace being generated while I'm testing the file itself in a live preview window. When I use <div> tags instead of a <span> the extra space disappears

Comment: But using a <div> tag causes the output to have a line break at the end which I would like to avoid

Comment: Back to my original thought .... this sounds like a standard old HTML thing where a carriage return before an inline element is whitespace and is rendered as a space. Whitespace before a block element is also whitespace but is not rendered. That's the way HTML has been since the year dot.

Comment: uh so I just fixed it....lol I added this line to my span tag: <span style="float: left;"></span>

Comment: my code is still a crap show though so i will try to reorganize it for sure

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help roamer!!!!

Comment: Well done! And no worries. I have had two yogurts and a bowl of porridge, so thanks for joining me for breakfast.

Comment: haha cheers, enjoy your breakfast!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got to the root of the problem, which was the fact that I really had no clue what I was doing with my ajax request. After a lot of research I was able to reformat much of my code. This is what I did:

First of all I changed my ajax request to this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: {name: timezone_offset_minutes},
    success: function(data){
    $('#timelyGreeting').text(data);
    }
});
```

Then in the header.php page where I want my greeting to display, I moved this line to the top of the page:

```
<?php include('includes/timely-greeting.php');?>
```

Then finally, I removed the  tags from the 'timely-greeting.php' plugin file and instead put in my 'header.php' in the exact spot where I wanted my greeting message to go:

```
<span id="timelyGreeting"></span>
```

Now I just to understand how data is actually getting passed in my ajax request because I'm worried I'm doing something hacky here...

Comment: hehe, so I still don't fully get how to handle my ajax request, specifically how to handle the 'data' variable. Right now it's technically sending the entire page's code in the request. Using 'exit;' stops the excess code from generating, but that still feels like a hacky way of doing things, when I probably should just figure out how to actually handle a dang ajax request..